# Python Celery: Updating task chain during execution

Tags: python-2.7, celery

When executing a celery task chain, it is possible to stop the chains execution as follows:

```
@celeryapp.task(bind=True)
def task(self, continue_task_chain):
    if not continue_task_chain:
        self.request.chain = None
```

Instead of cancelling the whole request chain however, I would like to modify self.request.chain with an alternate chain.

```
@celeryapp.task(bind=True)
def task(self, continue_task_chain):
    if not continue_task_chain:
        self.request.chain = another_chain
```

Is there a way to do this?